# Reading a csv within specific date range

Tags: python

I have the following code which reads a csv using DictReader and then creates a list from each column within the csv:

```
    myfile = csv.DictReader(open('data_in/' + filename + '.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)

    date, openp, highp, lowp, closep = [], [], [], [], []
    for line in myfile:
        if mdates.datestr2num(line['Date']) >= mdates.datestr2num('01/01/2014'):
            date.append(mdates.datestr2num(line['Date']))
            openp.append(int(line['Open']))
            highp.append(int(line['High']))
            lowp.append(int(line['Low']))
            closep.append(int(line['Close']))
```

The code works but as you can see when adding the columns to the relevant lists, I only include dates that are >= a specific date. This means that I have already read in the entire csv file, after which I only use a subset of that data based on date.

Is there a way to do the date check while reading in the csv so that I don't have to take up memory for data that im not going to use?

Many thanks.

Comment: Is the file sorted by date?

Comment: Yes the file is sorted by date

Comment: Just stop iterating when you hit a date that's too long ago. Also it's a waste to recompute the fixed date on every iteration. The result won't change. Compute it once before the loop.

Comment: Thanks that's a good point about only computing the fixed date once. But im not sure what you mean by 'stop iterating when I hit a date that's too long ago'. Do you mean I still have to read in the entire file using DictReader? I was hoping there was a way to only read in the correct date range (therefore not wasting memory)

Comment: It depends on whether your dates are sorted ascending (oldest first) or descending. If they are ascending then you have to loop through the old ones to get to the new ones. In that case what you have is as good as it can get. If the dates are descending then you can stop when you reach a date that is too old, as you know the rest will be too old as well. To do that just add an `else` clause to your `if` and `break` out of the loop.